# iOS Gesture recognition utilizing accelerometer (and gyroscope)

Tags: ios, artificial-intelligence, gesture-recognition

I would like to detect gestures on an iOS device using the accelerometer and perhaps the gyroscope. The Application should detect movements like drawing a circle or a rectangle in the air. I've found several papers on gesture recognition on iPhones but there is no actual code which I could use. I wonder if there is a library which could assist me in approaching this goal in any way? If not, I have to start building one on my own! :)
Thanks in advance!
Markus

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have to develop those functions on your own.  The built in gesture recognition features are all for touch based events.

Answer (score 1):

I related question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6368618/341970), it may help little.

Beside the [paper](http://www2.cs.fit.edu/~pkc/papers/tdm04.pdf) mentioned there, you might find interesting [this paper](http://www.mendeley.com/research/using-dynamic-time-warping-to-find-patterns-in-time-series/) too, page 363, 5. boundary conditions and page 364. I am curious how DTW works for your application. Good luck anyhow!

Comment: Somebody thought like me before me. :-p I was on the right track! :-)

Comment: Thank you very much, this seemes to be far much easier than the Hidden Markov Stuff I've found so far. I'm trying to evaluate this stuff a little and therefore dont want to put thaaat much effort into it. But I will definitely try the DTW!

Comment: I am glad you liked the idea. Please post your experience with the DTW, I am curious!

Comment: Soo, i have not implemented the DTW algorithm you described in your other post. But i have a little problem with understanding it. perhaps you can help me :)
https://skitch.com/reinerspass/fg66p/iphone-store-orientation-to-an-array-and-compare-stack-overflow 
The number in the lower left corner is ok, 5-2 is 3 + min of three times 0 is 0, so the result is zero.
But i get confused with the next one: 5-4 is 1 + min(0,0,3) is 1, you have 4 in your chart. It would be nice if you can give me e hint! :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: My mistake, thanks for pointing that out. The matrices are correct, just the explanation how I got them was wrong. The `D(0,*)` and `D(*,0)` are not zero but left out. The **columns** are computed first. I fixed these in the answer.

Comment: Ahh thank you very much! Now its clear and my app is working. I currently use the algorithm in a little drawing app which allows to record and then match gestures. So far I further evaluate it. The results are not that marvelous :) I think i have to normalize the inputvalues in a certain way.

Comment: Yes, I only gave a sketch of the algorithm. Please check the linked paper / google dwt, there are a number of ways to improve the basic algorithm. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use Core Motion and a lot of mathematical functions.

I'll take a guess (for which I'll be probably wrong): If you want to capture circular motions (drawing with the device a circle in the air in one plane), take regular samples (> 20 Hz) and save the maximum values of x, y and z in an array each (to recognize in all 3 planes). If you want the gesture to be 5 seconds long, keep 100 samples (at 20 Hz). Then analyze if any of the three arrays has values which change sinusoidally. If it does, you've got a gesture.

I guess it's a bit of trial and error, or drawing on paper a circle and guessing the accelerometer values in the progress of moving.

Hope you find the answer. I'm very interested already.

Comment: yes, you are on the right track, DTW (see the link at my answer) is better for gesture recognition.

Comment: thanks your idea! :) I'll try to implement @Ali's idea since it sounds very promising!