# DTW for 3D gesture recognition

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, accelerometer, gesture, gesture-recognition

I'm using DTW to compare gestures in 3D space, relying on 3axis accelerometer data, using Python MLPY module.

I'm in doubt whether I need to apply DTW to each axis (x, y, z) independently and then sum up the resulting costs or there is some way to combine the axis before running DTW. I think just running DTW on the norm of the vector is misleading, as this way you would just discard useful information.

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the Eucledian distance, see at the bottom of [my earlier answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6369947/341970)

Comment: Thank you! I think I'll do this way. I'm looking for a good C implementation of DTW, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @stef No, unfortunately, I could only Google too... :(

Comment: Same for me, I found this http://www.phon.ox.ac.uk/files/slp/Extras/dtw.html but it gives "Segmentation fault" even when I run it with the example data..