# Detect swing movement like dumbell bicep curl with android accelerometer

Tags: android, accelerometer, motion-detection

I want to create a game which detect arm movement with accelerometer . The kind of arm movement are the movement which commonly found in fitness club like dumbell bicep curl and the others.
my only concern is that I have no idea about the formula of swing movement and how to detect that with accelerometer.

maybe the best possible way is to detect the distance of swing movement from going up then start to going down. but still I have no idea how is the equation or formula .. any idea?

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is: try [dynamic time warping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6369947/341970).

Comment: what is that? I'm getting lost from the first paragraph :|

Comment: There is no such formula or equation that you are looking for. Instead, you have to build a database of gestures first. Then you have to compare the user's motion to the gestures in the database. The answer linked above tells you how to do that.