# Euler Angles from analog sensor data 9dof

Tags: javascript, accelerometer, three.js, gyroscope, euler-angles

I'm looking to compute euler angles based on analog sensor data in javascript. The sensor data includes gyro, accelerometer, and magnetometer data in 3d. The math is a little over my head, and looking for any help or tips.

Thanks!

Comment: Project is in node.js using serial to communicate with an arduino

Comment: The best resource I have found is Wolfram's [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerAngles.html). You may need to develop some basic functions to handle matrices, but they're not that hard once you get into it. If you provide examples of input and what you've tried so far, you'll get more help.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you are asking for. Is it sensor fusion that you are trying to implement? Or you already have it and you want to get Euler angles from the orientation (rotation matrix or quaternion)?

I have implemented **sensor fusion** for [Shimmer 2](http://www.shimmer-research.com/products-2/shimmer-revisions) devices based on this [manuscript](http://gentlenav.googlecode.com/files/DCMDraft2.pdf). I highly recommend it.

**Euler angles are evil**, don't use them. [They mess up the stability of your application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5578867/341970) and [they cannot be used for interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5580491/341970).

JavaScript seems a little odd choice for this type of task.