# Why are these 2 rotation matrices representing Quternions and Euler Angles not the same?

Tags: rotation, geometry, rotational-matrices, euler-angles, quaternions

The following is the representation for rotating about a unit quaternion {q0,q1,q2,q3} by an angle alpha:

```
q_0=cos(alpha/2)
q_1=sin(alpha/2)cos(beta_x)
q_2=sin(alpha/2)cos(beta_y)
q_3=sin(alpha/2)cos(beta_z)
```

Here,beta_x, beta_y and beta_z are the direction cosines of the unit quaternion, i.e. the axis about which I am rotating.

The rotation matrix corresponding to this is as follows: Let's call this **R1**

```
 1- 2(q_2^2 + q_3^2)   2(q_1 q_2 - q_0 q_3)    2(q_0 q_2 + q_1 q_3) 
2(q_1 q_2 + q_0 q_3)   1 - 2(q_1^2 + q_3^2)    2(q_2 q_3 - q_0 q_1) 
2(q_1 q_3 - q_0 q_2)   2( q_0 q_1 + q_2 q_3)   1 - 2(q_1^2 + q_2^2)
```

Now, suppose my rotation matrix is represented by using Euler angles instead: Let's call this **R2**

[image]

R2 rotates a vector by phi around x axis first, then by theta around the y axis and finally by psi around the z axis. Now, suppose my axis of rotation is in the y-z plane.This means that there is no rotation around the x-axis, only a combination of rotations around the y and z axes. **This means that phi is zero**, which means that **R2(3,2) is zero.**

Alternatively, this also means that cos(beta_x) is zero, since there is no rotation about the x-axis.This means that q_1 is zero.**However, if we look at R1(3,2), it is not zero, unlike R2(3,2).Why are these two representations not the same? What am I missing?**

Comment: **TL;DR** Most likely you run into the so-called double cover issue, see for example [Incorrect conversion from quaternions to euler angles and back](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15050505/341970). Please check.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Incorrect conversion from quaternions to euler angles and back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047471/incorrect-conversion-from-quaternions-to-euler-angles-and-back)

Comment: @Ali: Thanks for the reply! I'm stuck in a problem where I have to rotate an object by an arbitrary angle around an axis confined to the y-z plane and then find out the Euler angles which produced this.It is absolutely necessary that i only find the Euler angle set which has rotations about the y and z axis only. To do this, I am equating R1 and R2 and trying to solve for theta and psi, assuming phi is zero. How do you suggest I proceed with this condition in mind?

Comment: OK, now I have also read the question. So you suspect that you made somewhere and error during the derivation of the formulas? In any case, I believe this question belongs to http://math.stackexchange.com/ You probably have a better luck there than here. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful...

Comment: @Ali: I just took the formulas out of this page:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles

Comment: Euler angles represent a sequence of 3 rotations around axes in 3D space. You have different choices for the axes and the rotations order, which one did you choose?

Answer (score 0):

This statement is wrong.

> Now, suppose my axis of rotation is in the y-z plane.This means that
>   there is no rotation around the x-axis, only a combination of
>   rotations around the y and z axes. This means that phi is zero, which
>   means that R2(3,2) is zero.

For a rotation about (0,.6,.8), R2(3,2) would be
 `(1-cos)(.6)(.8)`
See [here](https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/angleToMatrix/index.htm)
I'd like to work on a visualization of this.

EDIT: Going [here](https://www.andre-gaschler.com/rotationconverter/) and entering Axis-angle of (0,.6,.8) and angle of 45 degrees gives `R2(3,2) = .1406` as expected, and it gives the Euler angles.

EDIT 2: SEVEN YEARS AGO?!  How did this appear on my computer?